# How to make my app work in all devices?

Tags: android

i made android app for minSdkVersion 23 and targetSdkVersion 23.while launching i saw that this can only support 5000 devices in 15000 devices.i want to make this app support for all devices.how can i do?

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.love.ksr_red_app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: change minSdkVersion to a lower value (15 for example) and the targetSdkVersion to the biggest value possible which is 27. that way your app will support probably 98% of devices. Take a look at this [distribution chart](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

Try making `minSdkVersion` to lowest OS version to which you make your app compatible with.

And make `targetSdkVersion` to the latest OS version available. This will make sure that your application is targeting towards all the devices available in the market and will compatible with them.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to make this app support for all devices.how can i do?

Well..., That looks practically impossible. Though you can try below thing... which will make your app support most of the devices that are present in the market

---

1) Launch android studio and Create new project

[image: picone]

2) Name new project

[image: pictwo]

3) select the minimum support version user friendly

[image: picthree]

> Look it will be supporting 96 % of the devices in the market

Things to keep in mind :

1. Very old devices are no more there in market like android 1.0 to 4.0
2. By doing this way it ensures you are going to give support to the maximum number of the devices you can
3. It will make and alter the things necessary for you in the project
4. Most importantly... you have to manage `exceptions` and `build versions` via code..!!
5. There are some devices like `VIVO` in india or other countries which takes `android` and modifies it to `FuntouchOS` which will not let you start your program `ON_BOOT_COMPLETED`... Such phones are based on android and not purely android like others.
6. Thats why it is not practically possible to support all the devices which shows you in `Google console` in numbers; `while uploading an app`

> Hope it helps you or someone else

Answer (score 0):

Change your buile.gradle with this configration.

```
**android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.websinfotech.apptophonecallexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}**
```